# Is there a way to wrap text to a new div/p/other element automatically without manually needing to manually or with .Js/js framework?

Tags: html, css, word-wrap, styling, text-styling

what i'm looking to do, is something akin to text-box wrapping in photoshop/illustrator/other, where you can write one paragraph, but if you "spill over" it will jump to another text box as if it's filling out that one.

I'm ideally looking for a way to do this with no javaScript, using only html/css if possible, or at least know this isn't possible and that i should move onto other prospects.

visual example of what i mean: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dzbhv.jpg

i tried every property of css text wrapping that i seen, along with web crawling but i haven't been able to see anything like what i'm looking for.

Comment: What decides when the jump should occur - in your example it seems nothing has led to that (not the end of a paragraph for example). Are you looking for HTML columns attribute?

Comment: There's a technique called CSS Shapes, some good examples can be found here: https://blog.logrocket.com/creative-text-flows-using-css-shapes/. I have never used it myself, I don't know if it can achieve what you need, but it seems at least worth a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was suggested a way that is close enough elsewhere, and I'm posting here to help anyone else who might need it, a free floating one does not seem to exist, however, the `column-(x)` properties seem to be the best option.

think to some documentation here: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_multiple_columns.asp

the way i implemented it was to assign a class to it that is self descriptive (threeColumnDiv in this case), which i will use any time i need to.

another thing which seems like maybe ideal is the grid-row properties (reference: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_grid-row.php.

If there's anything else desired, it seems you will have to do it in a custom manner, but i feel like those edge cases are rare enough it should not be a big deal.

Thanks for everyone's responces and help in the matter!

Answer (score -1):

You can set number of words seen to stop going out of the box (classic "Read more") but doubt you can do this with just html/css.

Ofc I could be wrong but see no way to html or css communicate, cut content on specific condition and jump in next div on their own.